# How to prevent "the literal stack isn't empty" error when using custom bib style?

Tags: bibtex, stack

I am using a customized bib style that is derived from the abbrvdin style. Unfortunatly I am getting the following error message:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6840 64-bit)
The top-level auxiliary file: master.aux
The style file: abbrvdinAnsgarDiss.bst
Database file #1: 04_Bib/MK_Diss.bib
ptr=1, stack=
% this bibliography is generated by abbrvdin.bst [8.2] from 2005-12-21
---the literal stack isn't empty
while executing---line 2034 of file abbrvdinAnsgarDiss.bst
(There was 1 error message)
```

The concerned line 2034 is running this function:

```
FUNCTION {begin.bib}
{ preamble$ empty$
    'skip$
    { preamble$ write$ newline$ }
  if$
  "\begin{thebibliography}{"  longest.label  * "}" * write$ newline$
  newline$
  "% this bibliography is generated by abbrvdin.bst [8.2] from 2005-12-21"
  newline$
  "%\protect\thispagestyle{Kapitelbeginnseite}"  %% (AR)
  write$ newline$ newline$
  "\providecommand{\url}[1]{\texttt{#1}}"
  write$ newline$
  "\expandafter\ifx\csname urlstyle\endcsname\relax"
  write$ newline$
  "  \providecommand{\doi}[1]{doi: #1}\else"
  write$ newline$
  "  \providecommand{\doi}{doi: \begingroup \urlstyle{rm}\Url}\fi"
  write$ newline$
}

EXECUTE {begin.bib} %<-- This is line 2034
```

The generated `.bbl` file looks like this:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}


%\protect\thispagestyle{Kapitelbeginnseite}

\providecommand{\url}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\expandafter\ifx\csname urlstyle\endcsname\relax
  \providecommand{\doi}[1]{doi: #1}\else
  \providecommand{\doi}{doi: \begingroup \urlstyle{rm}\Url}\fi

\bibitem[1]{Casanova.2015}
\textsc{Casanova}, M.; \textsc{Nodari}, L.; \textsc{Sagar}, A.;
  \textsc{Schermanz}, K.; \textsc{Trovarelli}, A.:
\newblock Preparation, characterization and NH3--SCR activity of FeVO4
  supported on TiO2--WO3--SiO2.
\newblock {In: }\emph{Applied Catalysis B: Environmental} 176-177 (2015), S.
  699--708

\bibitem[2]{Kleinhenz.2018}
\textsc{Kleinhenz}, M.; \textsc{Fiedler}, A.; \textsc{Lauer}, P.;
  \textsc{D{\"o}ring}, A.:
\newblock SCR Coated DPF for Marine Engine Applications.
\newblock {In: }\emph{Topics in Catalysis}  (2018)

\end{thebibliography}
```

What is the error message meaning by "literal stack is not empty"? Is this changing the resulting bibliography in any way or does it not matter? How can I get rid of this error message?

Answer (score 2):

as no test code is provided this is untested but it looks like you are missing

```
write$
```

after

```
  "% this bibliography is generated by abbrvdin.bst [8.2] from 2005-12-21"
```

the error message shows that this string is on the *non empty* stack, and your output shows that it was not written to the bbl file.